# Need to create a loop statement with iterations

Tags: sas

The recent elections required the mail delivery of party information pamphlet bundles. We want to determine how many man hours were spent delivering this advertising material, to the 50,000 registered voters in one electorate.

Each person can carry 100 pamphlet bundles, initially they can walk at 1 m/s, but with each delivery they become 0.01 m/s faster, to a maximum of 1.8 m/s.
    Create a loop statement in SAS with 20 iterations that will:

a> 1. Show the increase in speed with each delivery and the distance travelled by each person if the average delivery is 50 m apart. Ensure each iteration is shown in your result table.

2. Add in a condition to ensure that the speed does not exceed the maximum as specified above. How many bundles are delivered before maximum walking speed is achieved?

b> Use another code step to determine the total time spent delivering all 100 pamphlet bundles, and how long this would take to deliver to all 50,000 voters. Hint  speed=distance/time.

Below is the code for 1 a and b .

```
data q6;
speed =1;
do i = 1 to 20;
distance_in_meters +50;
speed+0.01;
bundles+100;
output;
end;
run;

data q6;
speed=1;
do i = 1 to 1000 until (speed>=1.8);
distance_in_meters + 50 ;
speed + 0.01;
bundles +100;
output;
end;
run;
```

i need help with b

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat vague question specifications from teacher.

> How long would this take

are sometimes trick questions where people reply with total man hours instead of trick answer wanted, elapsed time on clock.

For part two you need to compute each delivery time `(time = 50 / speed)` prior to adjusting speed, and accumulate `(total_time + time)`

For example:

```
--- LOG ---
Time (hms) per person to deliver 100 pamphlets: 0:58:26
Number of pamplets: 50000
Number of persons: 500
Total person time (hms) on delivery: 486:53:34
Time to deliver all items if all people start at same time: 0:58:26

%let ItemCount = 50000;
%let ItemsPerPerson = 100;
%let LoadedVelocity = 1; * m/s;
%let UnloadDistance = 50; * m;
%let UnloadVelocityIncrease = 0.01; * m/s;
%let VelocityMax = 1.8; * m/s;

data want_a1_perPerson;
  length index speedup distance speed 8.;
  speed = 1;
  distance = 0;
  do index = 1 to 20;
    * unload;
    speedup = ifn (speed < &VelocityMax, &UnloadVelocityIncrease, 0);
    speed + speedup;
    distance + &UnloadDistance;
    output;    
  end;
run;

data want_a2_perPerson;
  length index speedup distance speed load unloaded 8.;

  speed = 1;
  distance = 0;

  load = 100;
  unloaded = 0;

  do index = 1 by 1 until (speed >= &VelocityMax or load = 0);
    unloaded + 1;
    load + -1;

    speedup = ifn (speed < &VelocityMax, &UnloadVelocityIncrease, 0);
    speed + speedup;

    distance + &UnloadDistance;

    output;    
  end;
run;


data want_b;
  length index speedup distance speed load unloaded 8.;

  speed = 1;
  distance = 0;

  load = 100;
  unloaded = 0;

  do index = 1 by 1 until (load = 0);

    distance + &UnloadDistance;

    time_to_unload = &UnloadDistance / speed; * unit analysis: m / (m/s) = s;

    total_time + time_to_unload;

    unloaded + 1;
    load + -1;

    speedup = ifn (speed < &VelocityMax, &UnloadVelocityIncrease, 0);
    speed + speedup;

    output;
  end;

  personCount = &ItemCount / &ItemsPerPerson;
  personHours = personCount * total_time;

  putlog "Time (hms) per person to deliver 100 pamphlets: " total_time time7.;
  putlog "Number of pamplets: &ItemCount";
  putlog "Number of persons: " personCount;
  putlog "Total person time (hms) on delivery: " personHours time9.;
  putlog "Time to deliver all items if all people start at same time: " total_time time7.;
run;
```